# ReadWriteLock waiting for object to be set

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

`DependingService` depends on `service` object that is injected asynchronously and dynamically to `DependingService.setService(Object)`. If `DependingService.doSomething()` is called before `service` object is set, then thread should wait 5 seconds for `service` to be available.

How to do proper and effective locking? My first approach looks like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class DependingService {

    private final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Condition condition = rwLock.writeLock().newCondition();
    private Object service;


    // service injected dynamically by container
    public void setService(final Object service) {
        rwLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            this.service = service;
            System.out.println("Signalling");
            condition.signalAll();
        } finally {
            rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }


    public void doSomething() {
        rwLock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            if (service == null) {
                // we can't upgrade to write lock, so release read lock first
                rwLock.readLock().unlock();
                rwLock.writeLock().lock();
                try {
                    if (service == null) {
                        System.out.println("Waiting fo 5 seconds");
                        condition.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    // downgrade to read lock
                    rwLock.readLock().lock();
                    rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
                }
                if (service == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("service is null");
                }
            }

            // use the service
            System.out.println(service.toString());
        } finally {
            rwLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit:**
Note that `DependingService.setService(Object)` may be anytime and multiple times set to null or any other object.

Comment: How frequently is `setServive` called? Numerous times (100+) every second? Once every x seconds / minutes?

Comment: One issue with your code is that `condition.await(...)` can awake spuriously - so you should put that statement in a loop, in which case your timeout won't work any more.

Comment: assylias: normally it should be called only once, but noone never knows (it is actually in OSGi environment)

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of an easy way to build that behaviour with the high level API. See below a suggestion using a wait/notify pattern. Main points:

- `service` is `volatile` to ensure visibility without having to lock for reading
- `service` is always copied locally in `doSomething` to prevent a case where you check that service is not null then call `service.toString()` and get a NPE because `setService(null);` has been called in the meantime.
- the waiting time is adjusted at each while loop to make sure you don't wait more than 5 seconds.
- it uses basic synchronization, but only when service is null - in the base case where service is not null, there is no contention in `doSomething`. If you call `setService` many times every ms, you could face performance problems.

Note: not tested.

```
public class DependingService {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private volatile Object service;

    // service injected dynamically by container
    public void setService(final Object service) {
        this.service = service;
        synchronized(lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() throws InterruptedException {
        //make a local copy to avoid problems due to service becoming
        //null in the middle of the method
        Object localService = service; 
        if (localService == null ) {
            long end = System.nanoTime() + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            synchronized(lock) {
                while ((localService = service) == null) {
                    long waitNanos = end - System.nanoTime();
                    if (waitNanos < 0) break;
                    lock.wait(waitNanos / 1000000);
                }
            }
        }
        if (localService == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("timeout: service is still null");
        }
        // use the service
        System.out.println(localService.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you going through all that trouble to use nanos instead of millis?

Comment: @jtahlborn not necessary indeed. I tend to use nanotime by default when measuring a short period - but for 5 seconds currentMillis would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to use CountDownLatch like this:

```
public class DependingService {
    private final CountDownLatch serviceLatch = new CountDownLatch (1);
    private Object service;

    public void setService (final Object service) 
    {
        this.service = service;
        serviceLatch.countDown ();
    }

    public void doSomething () throws InterruptedException
    {
        if (!serviceLatch.await (5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            throw new RuntimeException ("Service is still null");

        // Service is not null here
        System.out.println (service);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not explicitly mentioned, but container may later call setService(null) so your approach would not work it that case. But thanks for introducing me CountDownLatch :-)